# SSIS datatype error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

whats the correct datatype to use in SSIS for the following Metadata on SQL Server table.

```
[End Date] DATA_TYPE=-9 TYPE_NAME=date  PRECISION=10    LENGTH=20
```

I'm trying to load data from excel source to ole db destination and i'm getting the following errors

> [OLE DB Destination [116]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. 
>   An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record
>   is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" 
>   Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast
>   specification". An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL
>   Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid
>   character value for cast specification".
>
> [OLE DB Destination [116]] Error: There was an error with OLE DB
>   Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[End Date] on OLE
>   DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status
>   returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential
>   loss of data.".
>
> [OLE DB Destination [116]] Error: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "OLE DB
>   Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error
>   code 0xC0209077 occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE DB
>   Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on
>   error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified
>   component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more
>   information about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The
>   ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (116) failed
>   with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination
>   Input" (129). The identified component returned an error from the
>   ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the
>   error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running. 
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information
>   about the failure.

Comment: What datatype are you using when you get the error?

Comment: For [End Date] in the OLE DB Destination, under 'External columns' i'm using 'database time [DT_DBTIME]' and under Input columns i'm using 'DT_DATE' to the column [Copy of End Date] from 'Derived column' transformation

Comment: Also [End Date] on Excel source 'External columns' is Unicode string [DT_WSTR] and on 'Output columns' its date [DT_DATE]

Answer (score 1):

Oftentimes when I'm loading dates and datetimes from flatfiles or Excel, I end up using a string (dt_str) and then casting it to a date/datetime in SQL.

I have had some luck having the flatfile data type be a dt_str but still having the SQL table be a datetime. Somehow it gets implicitly converted. But depending on the format of the date, this fails and I end up doing the cast approach.

I might also add, that Excel has been a troublesome source in my experience. If you can save as a .CSV or some other flat file, it seems to work better.

Comment: unfortunately its not letting me convert to dt_str, as i guess the source [End date] column is on dt_wstr

Comment: Ah, yeah. You could just use dt_wstr to get it to a nvarchar in SQL. The cast to date/datetime will work there as well.

Comment: you mean to date [DT_DATE] ?

Comment: i'm using data conversion transformation to convert from dt_wstr to  date [DT_DATE]

Comment: I meant load the dates as strings into a SQL table as nvarchar(50), and then you can use tsql to 'cast([ColName] as datetime)'

Comment: I fixed it. It was a datatype mismatch issue in one of the mappings. Thanks so much!